# Optional array in protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message for a tree defined like so:

```
message TreeNode {
    uint32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    repeated TreeNode children = 3;
}
```

I want to make children optional. But the compiler complains that we can't have optional with repeated.

The JSON I get from MessageToJson has a lot of nodes with empty children: `children: []`

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
json = MessageToJson(pb_obj)
```

How can I make the children optional so that it is not sent in JSON?

Comment: Which version of `protoc` are you using? With 22.0, your proto and a `TreeNode` without `children`, the JSON produced does not include an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

With `protoc` (22.0), I am unable to reproduce your issue:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

import foo_pb2


a = foo_pb2.TreeNode()
b = foo_pb2.TreeNode()
c = foo_pb2.TreeNode()

a.id = 1
a.name = "A"

b.id = 2
b.name = "B"

c.id = 3
c.name = "C"

a.children.extend([b,c])

print(MessageToJson(a))
print(MessageToJson(b))
```

Yields:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "A",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "B"
}
```